# Python Pandas Flattening JSON with keys, which are not equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are many good examples for Python Pandas for flattening JSON, if the Key's are equal. But I couldn't figure out, how I could bring that into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
{
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "item1": "data1",
            "item2": "data2",
            "item3": {
                "item4": {
                    "item5": "bla1",
                    "item6": "bla2",
                    "item7": "bla3"
                }
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "item1": "data3",
            "item2": "data4",
            "item3": {
                "item4": {
                    "item5": "bla4",
                    "item6": "bla5",
                    "item7": "bla6"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is that the Level 1 Key is not equal(1, 2, 3...). But that's the output which I am getting back from the API call.

What I want to do is this result in the DataFrame, without loop the JSON with a common Python script. I guess, there must be a simple Pandas workaround of how i can create the columns in a DF:

```
    item1 item5 item6 item7
0 1 data1 bla1  bla2  bla3
1 2 data3 bla4  bla5  bla6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(obj["data"]).T.reset_index(names="key")
           [["key"]].join(pd.json_normalize(obj["data"]) # `obj`is your json data
           .rename(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1], axis=1)
           .groupby(level=0, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
           .apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True))
      )
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  key  item1  item2 item5 item6 item7
0   1  data1  data2  bla1  bla2  bla3
1   2  data3  data4  bla4  bla5  bla6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using recursion. (`data` is your dictionary from the question):

```py
def get_kv(o):
    for k, v in o.items():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            yield k, v
        else:
            yield from get_kv(v)


df = pd.DataFrame({"index": k, **dict(get_kv(v))} for k, v in data["data"].items())
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  index  item1  item2 item5 item6 item7
0     1  data1  data2  bla1  bla2  bla3
1     2  data3  data4  bla4  bla5  bla6
```